# Recommendations for plots featuring div/daeva conspiracy to destroy civilization

Tags: system-agnostic, campaign-development, story

I'm putting together a plot in a Pathfinder RPG campaign where [divs](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary3/div.html#_div) (aka [daevas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daeva)) are orchestrating the downfall of civilization. I'm trying to set it up so that evil is working indirectly, by corrupting people and then letting them destroy themselves on both a personal and international scale.

Can anyone recommend literature on plots akin to this? The texts linked to on the daeva Wikipedia page are mainly treatises on history and religion. What I'm looking for is good plots fitting my above description. Any source is of interest - RPG sourcebooks, system agnostic plots, fairy tales, comics would all be welcome suggestions.  Also, please include why think that the source you recommend is a good one.

Comment: I imagine there must be a TV Tropes trope that matches; if so, they always have a ridiculously extensive mediography you could draw from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at **Azura's Wrath**, a game for Xbox 360. It have a fantastic plot with a twist on what a daeva actually is.

**Demon: The Fallen** is not exactly about Divs but can be easily adapted to your needs. It's the closest to what you need that I can think of.

**Aion** is an MMO with two angelic factions that have some solid lore, and their schemes can be adapted to cover your needs also (Search for things regarding "Lephar" and "Lepharists").